# How to create a formula based on some conditional formatted cells using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following situation:
I formatted using FormatConditions a range to show the style "Good" if the values within the range are between -2 and 2 and the style "Bad" if not, using this code:

```
With Range("D46:AC53")    
        .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
          "=IF(AND(D46<2,D46>-2),TRUE,FALSE)"
        With .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count)
            .SetFirstPriority
            With .Interior
                .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                .Color = RGB(198, 239, 206)
                .TintAndShade = 0
            End With
        .Font.Color = RGB(0, 98, 0)
        End With
       .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
          "=IF(AND(D46<2,D46>-2),FALSE,TRUE)"
        With .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count)
            .SetFirstPriority
            With .Interior
                .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                .Color = RGB(255, 199, 206)
                .TintAndShade = 0
            End With
        .Font.Color = RGB(156, 0, 6)
        End With
    End With
```

This is working great.

Now, I would like to create a macro button that will define that if all the range "D46:AC53" is "Good" to show the value "TRUE" in a specific cell. I used this code:

```
If Range("D46:AC53").Interior.Color = RGB(198, 239, 206) Then Range("c3").Value = "TRUE" Else Range("c3").Value = "FALSE"
```

Even the range D46:AC53 looks as "Good" the button returns me "FALSE".

Can you please help me? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,
Alexandra

I checked the fill color on the range formatted using the first code using right-click and Format Cells and it's showing me as not being filled. I manually formatted the Range D46:AC53 using the Style "Good" from Styles in Excel and that makes the button macro works.

Comment: `Interior.Color` doesn't detect CF colours - lots on this on the internet. Use displayformat or the criterion you are using for CF.

Comment: I am pretty new to VBA and I couldn't find anything. Can you please help me how should I adapt the codes so they will work ?

Comment: I changed the second code to:`If wstRev.Range("D46:AC53").DisplayFormat.Interior.ColorIndex = RGB(198, 239, 206) = 0 Then Range("c3").Value = "TRUE" Else Range("c3").Value = "FALSE"` but it's returning TRUE no matter what color I have on that range.

Comment: Not sure if that approach will work, you might have to check each cell. It's easier to use the CF criteria. If you're shading the cells if the value is between -2 and 2 use COUNTIFs to check how many satisfy that and if it's the same as the size of the range, bingo.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I didn’t find a solution on how to do this.l yet. Keep trying...

Comment: I don't have time now to spend any time on this but will take a look tomorrow if you are still stuck.

Comment: Appreciate! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this, as per my comment above.

```
If WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Range("D46:AC53"), "<2", Range("D46:AC53"), ">-2") = Range("D46:AC53").Count Then
    Range("c3").Value = "TRUE"
Else
    Range("c3").Value = "FALSE"
End If
```

Comment: Thanks for your time SJR. Still doesn't work. I used your code and it returns FALSE even it has to be TRUE. I tried everything...

Comment: Couple of things. (1) Is your CF definitely being applied correctly? Delete all CF and then re-apply (you can do that in code) (2) do you have any blanks in your range? I notice they are shaded green but not picked up by the COUNTIFS. If you use `If WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Range("D46:AC53"), "<2", Range("D46:AC53"), ">-2") +worksheetfunction.countblank(range("D46:AC53")) = Range("D46:AC53").Count Then` does that work?